# Can I get people to stop making my posts take away my reputation so I can stop deleting all of my posts?

Tags: discussion, support

I have barely any reputation left because of these bullies on arqade and I have no more answers because I had to delete them or a Cruel Hacker deletes ALL of my posts how Can I get This To STOP?!?!?

Comment: Bullies? Are you sure? As a stack overflow user (this was before I knew arqade existed) I've had numerous posts deleted/downvoted, and most of the time they were for a reason. As far as I am concerned this mainly because you don't look things up and because you get mad when people downvote. Also 53 rep isn't that bad.







P.S. The end of the sentence gives away that you are a kid. Kids are not allowed here according to COPPA. btw there are no cruel hackers, only diamond mods.

Comment: By changing your attitude: you seem to be taking a defensive position, whereas it is more helpful to first acquaint yourself with the workings of the Stack Exchange platform.

Comment: But I am a stack overflow user

Comment: @BronsonHunter that has nothing to do with what im saying

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's likely no "Cruel Hacker" deleting your posts. Posts can be deleted for all kinds of reasons. See this Meta post for more explanation of why posts might get deleted:[How does deleting work? What can cause a post to be deleted, and what does that actually mean? What are the criteria for deletion?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)

Downvotes happen for all sorts of reasons. If people leave comments (which they don't have to do, but sometimes people will), learn from them. Try to see if you can find a pattern - are you repeating things other answers have already said? Are you not being clear and detailed? Are you using proper capitalization/grammar where it makes sense to do so?

Upvotes are for answers the community finds helpful or useful. Unfortunately, downvotes are for...basically the opposite of that. If you're having trouble, you might want to read through some of the help centre guidance etc to try to help you write answers that are more appealing to the community and their standards.